# Toggle text of a button on click Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I'm looking to toggle the text of a button on the click using jquery, But it is not working properly.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnedit" runat="server" Text="Edit" Visible="True"
                    CssClass="actButton" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="btnedit_Click" />
```

On client-side:

```
$("#<%= btnedit.ClientID %>").click(function (e) {    
    $(this).text(function (i, text) {
        return text === "Edit" ? "Cancel" : "Edit";
    });
});
```

Can someone please advise me how to solve this?

Comment: then what is happening, is there any error in your console

Comment: You have tried with `$("#btnedit")` instead `$("#<%= btnedit.ClientID %>")`?

Comment: Does `OnClick="btnedit_Click"` do a full page postback? Does the text toggle work if you remove that attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I isolated your problem and you could try using this.

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/k7ww9x5s/1/)

Try using `val()` instead.

```
$("#btnedit").click(function (e) {    
    $(this).val("Edit" ? "Cancel" : "Edit");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector looks incorrect to me

```
 $("#<%= btnedit.ClientID %>")
```

should be

```
 $("#btnedit")
```